# Disable hover event on parent when mouse is over specific children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, unbind, hoverintent

I want to create a Slider with the effect that the `#slidertop` and `#sliderbottom` will disappear if the cursor reach the `#sliderarea` (area between both sections).

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEdPxR

This does work, but the effect start to early!

As long as the cursor is over the `#slidertop` and `#sliderbottom` sections, the `#slidertop` and `#sliderbottom` should not move.

I think that `.unbind()` function could be a solution, but I don't know whether it would work with my code or not.

**What I want**:

- Mouse over `#slidertop` & `#sliderbottom` -> no effect
- Mose over `#sliderarea` -> effect starts -> `#slidertop` & `#sliderbottom` disappears
- Mouse leave `#sliderarea` -> `#slidertop` & `#sliderbottom` appears

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chanckjh's solution is correct, but you have some weird markup going on in the pen. [Fix](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEdMJq)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#sliderarea').hoverIntent(getSmalls, getTalls);
```

Into

```
$('#slidertop, #sliderbottom').hoverIntent(getSmalls, getTalls);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `#slidertop` and `#slidertop` are part of the `#sliderarea` element. Therefore listening for `hover` event on this element, you're actually listening for `hover` on **all** its content, including `#slidertop` and `#slidertop`.

You could add another `<div>` inside `#sliderarea` (below the `#slidertop` and `#slidertop` divs), and place your content there. Then listen for `hover` event on that element, instead of the whole `sliderarea`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div id="sliderarea">
        <div id="slidertop"></div>
        <div id="sliderbottom"></div>
        <div id="slidercontent">... Your content here ...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add CSS:

```
#slidercontent {
    height    : 250px; /* same as for the #sliderarea */
    max-width : 800px; /* same as for the #sliderarea */
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // listen for hover event on #slidercontent:
    $('#slidercontent').hoverIntent(getSmalls, getTalls);
});

// unchanged part of your code:
function getSmalls(){
    $('#slidertop').animate({"height": 0}, 200);
    $('#sliderbottom').animate({"height": 0}, 200);
}

function getTalls(){
    $('#slidertop').animate({"height": 50}, 200);
    $('#sliderbottom').animate({"height": 50}, 200);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNLJKB)